# Do I need to use { get; set; } with c# fields that have no special actions when getting and setting

Tags: c#

I have been coding classes like this:

```
public class ReportViewModel
    {
        public string Status;
        public string DataSource;
        public String DataStore { get; set; }
        public PageMeta PageMeta { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Question> List { get; set; } 
    }
```

Note that most of the fields use { get; set; } except the first two which I let Visual Studio add for me.

What I am wondering is do I really need to use { get; set; }. It seems to me that VS2010 does not automatically add this so do I need it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between `Fields` and `Properties` in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446929/what-is-the-difference-between-fields-and-properties-in-c)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - worth linking to, but I think this asker is coming at that problem from a different direction, and as such this adds value as a separate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Property and Field in C# .NET 3.5+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-net-3-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ get; set; }` indicate autoimplemented properties. In .NET there is a difference between [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx). Normally fields should be private. They are used for some specific implementation and should in most cases be internal to the class. Properties on the other hand are used to encapsulate behavior that is exposed to the consumers.

Comment: Hello Darin, Being that these are used in a MVC3 viewmodel and that they are "dumb" with no logic required do you think it makes much difference to just have them as fields?

Comment: @SamanthaJ, now that you bring the topic about ASP.NET MVC, you should always use properties in your view model. The default model binder cannot bind to fields.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the default model binder. I have the following working: ViewModel file:   

public class ReportViewModel
    {
        public string Status;  etc etc...    CSHTML file:

@model xxx.ReportViewModel

<div>@Model.Status</div>

Comment: @SamanthaJ, in ASP.NET MVC the default model binder is responsible for binding view model's properties that your actions take as arguments from request values. So for example if you have the following controller action `public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model) { ... }`, and you send a request like `/home/foo?prop1=value1&prop2=value2`, the default model binder will automatically assign the corresponding properties of the view model from the request values. But it has to be public properties.

Answer (score 6):

You've created a class with two public *fields* (`Status` and `DataSource`) and three public *properties* (`DataStore`, `PageMeta` and `List`). I would advise against having public fields - and you should actually consider whether you *really* need all of these to be mutable properties at all.

There are [various advantages to using properties over public fields](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx), but the main one in my mind is that a property is logically part of the API of a class, whereas a field is logically an implementation detail. The property says *what* callers can do - a field says *how* a value is stored.

Comment: If you have really "dumb" properties like in this case with public get and set, is there a drawback in using public fields instead of properties?

Comment: @TomasJansson: Did you read the page I linked to in my answer?

Comment: Missed that it was a link, but I've read it now. Great description!

Answer (score 2):

If you want them properly exposed as properties, yes.

Answer (score 1):

They are different: your first two members are [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) - not [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). The others are properties with auto-implemented accessors.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't add the get and set you are using a field rather than a property.  Which in many cases won't make a lot of difference.  However, you can't databind to a field like you can with a Property.  So you would lose that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference.  The first two are [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) and the remainder are auto-[properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

The second one, the compiler generates a private backing field and some boiler-plate get/set methods.  These then allow you to access the properties like they were fields, but with the advantages only available to properties.

It is always recommended to hide fields behind properties, by either making them private and writing your own property around it or using an auto-property.

There's some advantages to properties.  One being that properties can be made read-only, or even write-only, or read-only with an internal write-only, etc.  Since they act just like methods, you can execute any arbitrary code inside of them.  This is useful for when you need to implement things like `INotifyPropertyChanged` or if the property is actually calculated from several fields behind it.

The other advantage is encapsulation.  You aren't tying yourself directly to the fields of the class, but rather the property.  So if some detail about the field changes (say it goes away and becomes calculated), by using the property you are insulating yourself from those implementation details.

You should certainly look at using properties (for now adding the `{ get; set; }`) for all cases.  They are good practice in that they provide a level of encapsulation that shields the user from implementation specific details.

Answer (score 1):

At all depends on how this class will be used.

If this is in your code, just used in your current product, then there isn't really much difference between fields (no `{get;set;}`) and properties (with the `{get;set;}`).

However in that case they probably shouldn't be `public`, make them `internal` or `private` instead so that it's clear that external code shouldn't use them.

If your class is going to be used by other assemblies then you should always convert public fields to properties.

The reason is that if you want to extend properties later on (i.e. add a body to the `set`) then your users can just get the new DLL from you. However if you've used fields then converting them to a property will look the same in the IDE, but require your users to recompile when they get the altered DLL.

Being `public` tells consumers that they can rely on that member being present, being a property gives you more control of how you deliver it to them.

Answer (score 0):

You *do not* have to, but this just coding stundart, with its pros and cons. 
Consider this link for more resources:

[Property Acessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655465/property-accessors/6655486#6655486)