# What is the advantage of using auto-implemented properties with the default access, instead of using public fields?

Tags: c#, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/c-public-fields-versus-automatic-properties)
>   [Do I need to use { get; set; } with c# fields that have no special actions when getting and setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967579/do-i-need-to-use-get-set-with-c-sharp-fields-that-have-no-special-actions)

Consider these two options:

```
public int Foo { get; set; }

public int Foo;
```

They seem to be semantically equivalent, and I believe they will even compile to the same IL. So what is the advantage of using the property? Seeing a public field makes me feel uneasy, but I can't think of any concrete advantage to using the property syntax instead. If an explicit getter and setter are required in the future, `public int Foo;` can be replaced by `public int Foo { ... }` with no other changes necessary. The best I can come up with is that the property syntax just *feels* better, but I can hardly use this reason to convince someone else.

What is the advantage (if any) of using the property syntax in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876197/c-why-have-empty-get-set-properties-instead-of-using-a-public-member-variable

Comment: [See Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7967619/621962) in to the question you've duplicated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/c-public-fields-versus-automatic-properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480627/why-wont-anyone-accept-public-fields-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277572/should-i-use-public-properties-and-private-fields-or-public-fields-for-data

Comment: Voted to close myself, my apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantages are:

1. Future-proofing your API - If you later need logic in the getter or setter, your public API doesn't change.
2. Data binding - Most data binding frameworks only work against Properties, not Fields.

Comment: Plus you can't declare fields on interfaces.

Comment: For #1, doesn't the API stay the same? Outside developers will still write `x.Foo = bar`, regardless of whether `Foo` is a field or property. #2 makes sense.

Comment: I would add 3. Object-relational mapping - most frameworks work against properties.

Comment: @Matthew and tomorrow you decide to make setter private.

Comment: @Matthew from the C# point of view, the syntax is the same, but the IL is quite different: a property get is rewritten as a call to the method `get_Foo()`.

Comment: @Matthew It's a breaking change.  You need a recompile, where an auto-property to a property with a custom implementation can just swap out the assembly directly.

Comment: @Andrey: Sure, but that problem exists whether you use a field or a property with a public setter. I agree this using a field is not the right solution, but I don't think that is one of the reasons why.

Comment: @phoog: I don't think that's true in this case: "A non-virtual property getter or setter that contains no instructions other than the field access will be inlined by the compiler" http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/46342

Comment: @Matthew by which compiler, the C# compiler or the jitter?  I believe it is the jitter, which means that the IL will show the call to `get_Foo()`.

Comment: @phoog: Ah, thanks for the clarification. That also answers my question about the breaking change, I was confused how it could be a breaking change if it was the same IL.

Answer (score 0):

*Pros*

- Easy declaration

*Cons*

- Can not set a `breakpoint` inside set/get
- Can not have a code inside get/set
- Do not working on WPF DataBinding
- No concept like a `default value` for the property, as there is no `default field` behind it.

*Pros* and *cons* are strictly related to the project implementation.

Just a couple of hints, pretty sure others will add something else...

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe they will compile to the same IL, as get and set for properties are actually functions on the IL level and when dealing with reflection. Here are some reasons to do it though:

1. Reflection!
2. Serialization/Deserialization only works on public properties, not public fields.
3. Debugging, you can set break points on a get or a set, which can help to track down when the variable is accessed, specifically if you are seeing a goofy value and you don't know where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason that we don't use auto-implemented properties is for those serialization mechanisms that serialize the members and not the properties (such as binary serialization for .Net remoting).

In this case, if you have two applications that compile the same class separately and exchange a serialized copy of the class, there is no guarantee that it will deserialize correctly since you can't control the names of the private members.